# Unable to receive message from WEB-SPHERE MQ queue by using Citrus Frame work xml test cases

Tags: citrus-framework

I am trying to receive messages from web-sphere mq queue by using citrus framework by defining actions in XML-test-cases. as shown below.

```
<receive endpoint="jms:Queue_Name?timeout=1000">
  <selector>
    <element name="correlationId" value="303132333435363738393130313131323133313431353136"
  </selecotr>
  <message>
  </message>
</receive>
```

I tried mentioning correlation id with hexadecimal value and ASCII value but I am unable to get the message I am getting `ACTION TIME OUT EXCEPTION`. I cross checked correlation id that existed in WEB-SPHERE MQ with mentioned correlation id in xml. but without selector tag I am able to get the message that was inserted first in the queue based on time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give correlation ID value like this it will work for you

```
<receive endpoint="jms:Queue_Name?timeout=1000">
  <selector>
    <element name="correlationId" value="ID:${varible consisting og hexa value}"
  </selecotr>
  <message>
  </message>
</receive>
```